# Because textview product counter is repeated in grid view using BaseAdapter

Tags: android, baseadapter, android-gridview, onitemclick, getview

Because it repeats the product counter which is a TextView; I have the following scenario:

1. The user selects the product, and applies the quantity.
2. From the Activity and not from the Adapter I show the quantity of the selected product as seen in the image.
3. Everything works perfect, until under the screen and the counter magically passes to another product, I have implemented these methods by suggestion:

   ```
   @Override
   public long getItemId(int position)
   {
       return position;
   }

   @Override
   public int getItemViewType(int position)
   {
       return position;
   }
   ```

and still I still get this error. I have also tried to modify the counter from the Adapter but the same thing happens. I want that counter to stay fixed and not update when under the screen.

Adapter:

```
   public class ProductoAdapter extends BaseAdapter
   {
    private Activity activity;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private ArrayList<Producto> listadoProductos;
    private ArrayList<Producto> productosPedidos;

    Producto producto;

    Empresas pedido;

    public final int TYPE_NOTICIA=0;
    public final int TYPE_LOAD=1;
    private gestionSharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
    private Context context;
/*
    OnLoadMoreListener loadMoreListener;
*/
    boolean isLoading=false, isMoreDataAvailable=true;
    vars vars;
    public static int contador;

    public static int i;
    public static int contadorGeneral;
    private NumberFormat numberFormat;
    ImageLoader imageLoader = ControllerSingleton.getInstance().getImageLoader();

    public ProductoAdapter(Activity activity, ArrayList<Producto> listadoProductos)
    {
        this.activity=activity;
        this.listadoProductos=listadoProductos;
        productosPedidos=new ArrayList<Producto>();
        vars=new vars();
        sharedPreferences=new gestionSharedPreferences(this.activity);
        contador=0;
        contadorGeneral=0;
        producto=new Producto();

       /* LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).registerReceiver(mMessageReceiver,
                new IntentFilter("custom-message"));*/
    }

  /*  public BroadcastReceiver mMessageReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver()
    {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
        {
            // Get extra data included in the Intent
            producto = (Producto) intent.getSerializableExtra("producto");
            Toast.makeText(context, producto.getNombreProducto()+producto.getNumeroDeProducto() ,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    };*/


    @Override
    public int getCount()
    {
        return listadoProductos.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Producto getItem(int position)
    {
        return listadoProductos.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position)
    {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position)
    {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup)
    {
        numberFormat = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(Locale.GERMAN);

        if (view == null)
        {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.producto_row_layout, viewGroup, false);

            Log.i("martin","null");
        }
        else
        {
            Log.i("martin","llenoooooooooo");
        }
        final Producto producto = getItem(position);

        ImageView imagenProducto = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imagenProducto);

        TextView nombreProducto = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.nombreProducto);
        TextView cantidadProducto = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.cantidadProducto);
        TextView precioGeneralProducto = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.precioGeneralProducto);
        TextView precioPideProducto = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.precioPideProducto);
        TextView ahorroProducto = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.ahorroProducto);



        if (producto.getImagenProducto().toString().equals("http://fasttrackcenter.com/pide/app/"))
        {
            imagenProducto.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_not_image_found);
        }

        else
        {
            Glide.with(activity).
                    load(producto.getImagenProducto().toString()).
                    thumbnail(0.5f).into(imagenProducto);
        }

        nombreProducto.setText(producto.getNombreProducto()+" x "+producto.getCantidadProducto()+" "+producto.getUnidadProducto());

        //cantidadProducto.setText(producto.getCantidadProducto());
        precioGeneralProducto.setText("$"+numberFormat.format(Double.parseDouble(producto.getPrecioGeneralProducto())));
        precioGeneralProducto.setPaintFlags(precioGeneralProducto.getPaintFlags()| Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG);
        precioPideProducto.setText("$"+numberFormat.format(Double.parseDouble(producto.getPrecioPideProducto())));
        int valorahorro=(Integer.parseInt(producto.getPrecioGeneralProducto()))-(Integer.parseInt(producto.getPrecioPideProducto()));
        ahorroProducto.setText(""+"$"+numberFormat.format(Double.parseDouble(""+valorahorro)));

        return view;
    }

}
```

Activity:

I use a TextView as a counter which is initially invisible, but when it is selected, it is visible with the quantity of product selected.

From the activity I use this method:

```
 @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
    {
        Producto producto = (Producto) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);

        final View contadorImagenProductoBolsa = Pedidos.this.findViewById(R.id.contadorProductoImagenBolsa);
        TextView test1TextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.contadorProductoImagenBolsa);


        mostrarDialogoDetalle(test1TextView,position,producto.getIdProducto(),producto.getImagenProducto(), producto.getNombreProducto(),
                producto.getCantidadProducto(),producto.getUnidadProducto(), producto.getPrecioGeneralProducto(),producto.getPrecioPideProducto(),
                producto.getAhorroProducto());

    }
```

Has anyone had this happen? how did they solve it?

[image]

Here it is perfect, but when I go under the screen and I go back and up, observe how the counter happens to another product inexplicably:

[image]

I want an effective help and a possible snippet if it is the case of an incorrect adapter or activity.

Thank you.

Comment: you have to store that particular position when it click .so while you scroll or move that position show only text. this happens because of your listview is re use cell .

Answer (score 0):

I think You have to add ViewHolder For ProductoAdapter  Like:

```
class ViewHolder
{
      TextView nombreProducto,cantidadProducto
      ,precioGeneralProducto,precioPideProducto,ahorroProducto;
      ImageView imagenProducto;

public ViewHolder(View view){

     imagenProducto = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imagenProducto);
     nombreProducto = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.nombreProducto);
     cantidadProducto = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.cantidadProducto);
     precioGeneralProducto = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.precioGeneralProducto);
     precioPideProducto = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.precioPideProducto);
     ahorroProducto = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.ahorroProducto);


}
}
```

Use setTag and getTag For ViewHolder Like:

```
ViewHolder holder;
    if (view == null)
    {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.producto_row_layout, viewGroup, false);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        Log.i("martin","null");
    }
    else
    {    holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        Log.i("martin","llenoooooooooo");
    }

    final Producto producto = getItem(position);
    if (producto.getImagenProducto().toString().equals("http://fasttrackcenter.com/pide/app/"))
    {
        holder.imagenProducto.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_not_image_found);
    }

    else
    {
        Glide.with(activity).
                load(producto.getImagenProducto().toString()).
                thumbnail(0.5f).into(holder.imagenProducto);
    }

    holder.nombreProducto.setText(producto.getNombreProducto()+" x "+producto.getCantidadProducto()+" "+producto.getUnidadProducto());
    .
    .
    .
 view.setTag(holder);
    return view;
```

i hope this is help you